An OCR steps to detect and extract the line pairs english text from image

I am trying to extract the text from an image using OCR. The challenge I am facing is how to map the key and value. For example, the key - Last Name should have the value XYZ. After getting the key value pair, I need to draw a bounding box around the identified key value text.

You'll want to find bounding boxes around paragraphs first.
In the end, you can just erode the image enough so that lines join into black blobs, and then find the first black pixel, and then find all black pixels that touch that pixel, or an adjacent black pixel, noting down the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates of all these pixels. The two resulting points give you the rectangular bounding box around a paragraph.
You then remove that rectangle from the image, and find the first black pixel, and repeat the procedure above.
You end up with a set of pairs of points, each pair describing a paragraph bounding box.
You then just do OCR on these rectangles individually; the top line will be your key, the bottom line will be your value. Easy!
